# Changing date variable into a new format, consistently

Tags: python

Given a variable that represents a date in this format:

current_date = '9/23/2019'

Write a few lines of code that will reliably turn it into this format:

new_date = '092319'

It needs to work for every possible day of the year. So those zeroes always need to be added when the month or day is a single digit number.

I want to automate a part of my job at work and this is the only issue standing in my way. The only way I can think of doing this would involve like 1000 if statements.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to change the current_date to this format :
Year,Month,Day and then we use datetime library to help you writing the date into the format you wish !

```
**the code :**
L = current_date.split('/')
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime(int(L[2]),int(L[1]),int(L[0]))
new = a.strftime("%x") # this will give you this output '09/23/19'
new_date = ''.join(new.split('/')) #and you get what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "current_date" is always valid and no validation is required and the input format is always the same, you could do something like this:

```
def replace_days_or_months(old_date):
  new_date = old_date if len(old_date) > 1 else "0" + old_date
  return new_date

def change_date_format(date):
  old_days, old_month, old_year = date.split("/")
  new_day = replace_days_or_months(old_days)
  new_month = replace_days_or_months(old_month)
  new_year = old_year[-2:]
  new_date = new_day + new_month + new_year
  return new_date

new_date = change_date_format("9/23/2019")
```